# How to pass object with different property name to a same function that can accept that paramemters

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

we updated object property that a function accept but some function in other files still accept old parameter, so how to call that function that can be valid for both type a functions
here is a just example

```
export interface oldTypeObject {
  type: string;
  name: string;
}

export interface newTypeObject {
  type: string;
  title: string;
}
```

and functions are

```
function1(data:oldTypeObject ){
 //somecode
}

function2(data:newTypeObject  ){
 //somecode
}
```

so now I want to call any function with same parameter like

```
function1({type:"Type",title|name : "Any Name or title"});
function2({type:"Type",title|name : "Any Name or title"});
```

There is anyway to do so in javascript/Typscript?

Answer (score 1):

you could use a multi typing like this to ensure that it is one or the other.

```
functionH(data: oldTypeObject | newTypeObject) {
    if ((data as oldTypeObject).name) {
        function1(data as oldTypeObject);
    } else {
        function2(data as newTypeObject);
    }
}
```

While being a bit bulkier then [@Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/876038/alexander)s solution it is the stricter typed one which might be what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the property that is deprecated as optional to the new type of change the oldTypeObject to add title

```
export interface newTypeObject or oldTypeOject {
  type: string;
  title: string;
  name?: string;
}
```

Comment: But It will give error on oldTypeOject as title is not present

Comment: make title optional

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for function overloads

```
export interface oldTypeObject {
  type: string;
  name: string;
}

export interface newTypeObject {
  type: string;
  title: string;
}

function handleData(data: newTypeObject): void;
function handleData(data: oldTypeObject): void;
function handleData(data: any): void {
 console.log(data.type)
  if (data.name) {
    console.log(data.name)
  }
  if (data.title) {
    console.log(data.title)
  }
}

const a = {
  type: 'hello',
  name: 'fizz'
}

const b = {
  type: 'goodbye',
  title: 'buzz'
}

handleData(a);
handleData(b);
// no errors
```